# Angular: How to add children under loadChildren dynamically?

Tags: angular

I have this AppInitService for APP_INITIALIZER for me to set the routes dynamically because the routes information will be coming from the API.

But, I do not know how to set or provide children routes within loadChildren module.

**Expectation**: **routes.children** with **layoutChildrenRoutes** under **LayoutRoutingModule** will be modified in **AppInitService**
Example code:

This is not working.

**AppInitService**

```
      const layoutChildrenRoutes = [
        {path: 'test', component: TestComponent},
        {path: 'home', component: DynamicContentComponent}
      ];

      //** update the index route */
      config[layoutConfigIndex] = {
        ...config[layoutConfigIndex],
        // loadChildren: () => import('./modules/layout/layout-routing.module').then(m => {
        //   let routes = m.routes;
        //   routes[0].children = layoutModuleConfigChildren as Routes;
        //   return routes;
        // }),
        loadChildren: () => import('./modules/layout/layout.module').then(m => {
          return m.LayoutModule;
        }),
      }
```

**LayoutModule > LayoutRoutingModule**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { 
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class LayoutRoutingModule {}
```

I am out of ideas, did some trial and errors but none of those worked.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to build add routes dynamically in angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928030/is-it-possible-to-build-add-routes-dynamically-in-angular-2)

Comment: @NarenMurali unfortunately it doesnt

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42224109/5058682) help?